# how can I use the word "class" cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I am doing an e-learning application using CakePHP.

The problem is that I need to use the word "class" in the Controller so I can get a class link http://www.site.com/class/

Is there a way to use the word "class" or not?

I am currently using classroom (http://www.site.com/classroom) but the word itself is long.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend it. Check out http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php

> You cannot use any of the following words as constants, class names, function or method names. Using them as variable names is generally OK, but could lead to confusion.

Pick a different name, like 'rooms', or leave it as classrooms. Or use Cake's routing.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I will try routing. I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have a controller named `class` because that's a PHP restriction, but you can use [routing](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#connecting-routes) to make the URL `/class` correspond to a controller that has any name you like.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I will try routing. I haven't tried it yet.